# Обязательно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

В обед нам разносили еду, каждому — свой поднос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, постановка тире в данном случае требуется: это неполное предложение с пропущенным членом предложения (сказуемое «Разносили» или «Давали»). Пропущенный член практически во всех случаях легко восстанавливается за счёт контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Тире ставится в обязательном порядке.

Это БСП, второе предложение является двусоставным эллиптическим вида "дополнение - подлежащее". Тире ставится в связи с наличием паузы в речи.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Эллиптические предложения следует отличать от неполных.

(1) В эллиптических предложениях сказуемого нет, и его не надо домысливать, например:

Смелый к победе стремится, смелым – дорога вперёд.Так вот в чём прелесть полёта в небо!

Она – в паденье!

(2) В неполных предложениях пропущенное сказуемое (или другие члены предложения) восстанавливается по контексту, причем это сказуемое уже НАЗВАНО:

Мир освещается солнцем, а человек – знанием. Береги платье снову, а честь – смолоду. Налево шумела забытая ель, направо – плакучая ива. Иван Иванович бреет бороду два раза в неделю, а Иван Никифорович – один раз.

Answer (score 1):

Тире не требуется, но возможно как авторский знак.

Comment: 1) Перед постановкой знака препинания требуется определить вид синтаксической конструкции. 2) Любой авторский знак - это не прихоть автора, а определенный оттенок смысла. 3) В эллиптических и неполных предложениях нет авторских знаков, там оба варианта равноправны и соотносятся со структурой и интонацией. 4) А паузу в речи вы не делаете? И тонические ударения надо расставить:В обЕд нам разносили едУ, кАждому — свой поднОс.

Comment: Вы же пишете: "Тире ставится в обязательном порядке". Нет? А теперь говорите: оба варианта равноправны.
Паузу, естественно, не делаю. Если это не стихи.

В обЕд котАм разносИли едУ,
кАждому - свОй поднОс.

Вот тут я бы поставил тире.

Comment: При решении подобных задач пауза иногда воспринимается субъективно, поэтому надо рассматривать схему тонических ударений. Вот примеры с двумя решениями: "МИр освещается сОлнцем, а человЕк – знАнием". Здесь параллельная интонация, пауза, тире. "Мир освещается сОлнцем, а человек знАнием". Нет параллельной интонации, нет паузы и тире.

Comment: А теперь попробуем построить наш предложение без паузы: "В обед нам разносили едУ, каждому свой поднОс". Совершенно не читается, так как одинаковой интонацией соединены разноструктурные предложения. Без паузы  после слова "каждый" можно использовать такой вариант: "В обЕд нам разносили едУ -  каждому свой поднОс".

Comment: Тире тут нужно как способ акцентировать логическим ударением СВОЙ. Ведь смысл не в том, что каждому поднос, а в том, что каждому свой. Ср.: В обЕд нам разносили едУ - каждому целый поднОс.